# Filter array that doesn't have specific object

Tags: mongodb

I've a document that have a key that is a array, how can i search on all documents where the array doesn't have a specific object?

Some of my documents are:

```
{
    "sku": "x",
    "datas": [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 1, b:2}]
}
```

and some others:

```
{
    "sku": "y",
    "datas": [{c: 0}, {a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 1, b:2}]
}
```

The result that i want is `sku "x"` because it does not have `{c: 0}`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use the `$not` operator to negate an `$elemMatch` term:

```
db.my_data.find({
    datas: {
        $not: {
            $elemMatch: {c: 0}
        }
    }
})
```